# How to optimize IN query on indexed column

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a table with over 50M records. One of the fields is `COLOR_CODE`. I've set an index on the column `COLOR_CODE` like this:

```
"mytable_colorcode_idx" btree (color_code)
```

I'm noticing that when I run the query below, the execution time is higher

```
SELECT count(total_amount) FROM mytable 
WHERE color_code in ('red','green') and sale_date = '1970'
```

However, the execution time is faster with `OR` clause:

```
SELECT count(total_amount) FROM mytable 
WHERE color_code = 'red' or color_code = 'green' and sale_date = '1970'
```

Query plan for `IN`

```
explain analyze SELECT count(total_amount) FROM mytable 
WHERE color_code in ('red','green') and sale_date = '1970'
                                                                            QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2074238.07..2074238.08 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=63520.150..63520.150 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=53504.73..2069923.27 rows=1725919 width=6) (actual time=3509.920..63080.519 rows=1727037 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((color_code)::text = ANY ('{red,green}'::text[]))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5067635
         Filter: (sale_date = 1970)
         Heap Blocks: exact=38679 lossy=496680
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_colorcode_idx  (cost=0.00..53073.26 rows=1725919 width=0) (actual time=3501.777..3501.777 rows=1727037 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((color_code)::text = ANY ('{red,green}'::text[]))
 Planning time: 0.165 ms
 Execution time: 63524.100 ms
(10 rows)
```

Query plan for `OR`

```
explain analyze SELECT count(total_amount) FROM mytable 
    WHERE color_code = 'red' or color_code = 'green' and sale_date = '1970'

    QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2081265.36..2081265.37 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=18895.998..18895.998 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=56223.06..2076956.39 rows=1723588 width=6) (actual time=161.335..18468.146 rows=1727037 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (((color_code)::text = 'red'::text) OR ((color_code)::text = 'green'::text))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5067635
         Filter: (((color_code)::text = 'red'::text) OR (((color_code)::text = 'green'::text) AND (sale_date = 1970)))
         Heap Blocks: exact=38679 lossy=496680
         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=56223.06..56223.06 rows=1725919 width=0) (actual time=153.683..153.684 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_colorcode_idx  (cost=0.00..663.35 rows=20655 width=0) (actual time=3.935..3.935 rows=26768 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((color_code)::text = 'red'::text)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_colorcode_idx  (cost=0.00..54697.91 rows=1705264 width=0) (actual time=149.745..149.746 rows=1700269 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((color_code)::text = 'green'::text)
 Planning time: 0.162 ms
 Execution time: 18896.785 ms
(13 rows)
```

**Update**

If I add an index (color_code, total_count, and sale_date) I notice that no index is used at all. Rather it does a partial scan.

```
"mytable_color_total_count_sale_Date_idx" btree (color_code, total_count, sale_date)  



                                                                      QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2099755.26..2099755.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=97066.585..97066.586 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=2099755.04..2099755.25 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=97063.512..97069.838 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2098755.04..2098755.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=97061.531..97061.532 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..2096119.69 rows=1054140 width=6) (actual time=27782.491..96730.232 rows=841604 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((sale_date = 1970) AND ((color_code)::text = ANY ('{red,green}'::text[])))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4196103
 Planning time: 0.161 ms
 Execution time: 97069.896 ms
(10 rows)
```

**Question**

Is there a way I can optimize by `IN` clause query other than turning it into an `OR` clause?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it wasn't using the index since I didn't see the additional row and the execution time was higher. I've modified the question to ask how the IN query can be optimized rather than missing index. Thanks

Comment: Is this fully repeatable?  It looks to me like the second query is faster simply because the first query already read all the data from disk into memory, so the 2nd one didn't need to.  Swap back and forth between the two queries repeatedly and see how the timings compare.  Also, it would be good to do `explain (analyze, buffers)`, especially if you can turn track_io_timing on first.

Comment: @Lennart Can you please explain further. Not sure I understand.

Comment: @Anthony, I've added a little longer explanation as an answer

Comment: It is unlikely that adding that new index would directly cause a different index to stop being used.  But if you look at the cost estimate of the first and last executions plans, they are almost identical to each other.  Since the statistics collector uses random sampling, small differences in the sample use could cause different plans to come out on top when the estimated costs are so similar.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare performance of:

```
WHERE color_code in ('red','green') and sale_date = '1970'
```

with:

```
WHERE color_code = 'red' or color_code = 'green' and sale_date = '1970'
```

because they are not logically equivalent (will return different results). A trivial example:

```
 with T (color_code, sale_date) as ( 
     values ('red', '1970'), ('green','1969')
 ) 
 select * from T 
 where color_code in ('green', 'red') 
   and sale_date = '1970';

 color_code | sale_date 
------------+-----------
 red        | 1970
(1 row)
```

However:

```
with T (color_code, sale_date) as ( 
    values ('red', '1970'), ('green','1969')
) 
select * from T 
where color_code = 'green' or color_code = 'red' 
  and sale_date = '1970';

color_code | sale_date 
------------+-----------
 red        | 1970
 green      | 1969
(2 rows)
```

In short `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` so your optimized expression `A OR B AND C` is evaluated as `A OR (B AND C)`. Your original expression is evaluated as `(A OR B) AND C`.

For the comparison to be meaningful, you need to change your query to:

```
select * from T 
where (color_code = 'green' or color_code = 'red') 
  and sale_date = '1970';
```

My guess is that you won't see much difference performance-wise with that and your original expression.

That said, I would suggest an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON ... (sale_date, color_code)
```

Comment: I think you hit the point that the two queries in OP's post are not the same logically speaking, so the question from the OP is somewhat not valid (based on the results of the two logically different queries).

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference in timing you see is simply a caching effect, based on which query you ran first.  It is probably not a real difference caused by how you specify the query (Although as Lennart described, your queries are not really equivalent as you are missing parentheses around the OR part--although all your rows seem to meet `sale_date = '1970'` anyway, so this difference is important in general, but doesn't make a difference in the exact example)

There some things you can do that might make both specifications of this query faster.

For one, look at this line:

```
     Heap Blocks: exact=38679 lossy=496680
```

This means that your work_mem is not large enough to hold the entire bitmap.  All of those lossy blocks need to have every row in them rechecked, which takes time.  Increasing work_mem would prevent this and should speed up the query.  Ideally the lossy blocks would drop to zero (at which point the 'lossy' label wouldn't be displayed anymore.

Second, having an index `on mytable (color_code, sale_date, total_count)` could allow for index-only scans, because all needed data would be in the index and it wouldn't have to visit the table at all (assuming the table is kept well-vacuumed).

These are mutually exclusive: if you do the index-only scan rather than the bitmap scan, then work_mem no longer matters.

Comment: My PostgreSQL runs on RDS. Should I just use a bigger RDS instance or is there a way to specifically increase `work_mem`. On that note...how would `Heap Blocks: exact=38679 lossy=496680` look if I had a bigger `work_mem` would `lossy` number go down? Asking so that I can check after increasing `work_mem`. Can you please explain what you mean by well-vacuumed. Does that mean that no updates are done to the table? Also, after creating the index on (color_code, total_count, and sale_date) I'm noticing that no index is being used. It is only doing partial scan

Comment: I've updated the question with results of adding an index `on mytable(color_code, sale_date, total_count)`

Comment: You can change work_mem in RDS without changing your instance class.  Of course you need to have enough memory to support the increased value, but the default setting of work_mem is conservative--unless you have a lot of simultaneous connections you should not have a problem increasing it.

Comment: well-vacuumed here would mean that `select relallvisible, relpages, relallvisible/relpages as ratio  from pg_class where relname='mytable'` is high.  Say, above 0.90.  Frequent updates might be OK, as long as it also gets frequent vacuums.